# Combining multiple text files into one in Java

Tags: java

I have a folder with multiple text files and I would like to put them all into one text file. I was wondering if I am able to use File reader but my code is not working.

```
    public class All{

      public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

      File file = new File("all.txt");
      file.createNewFile();
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
      writer.write("alex/Desktop/1.txt"); 
      writer.write("alex/Desktop/2.txt");
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();

      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); 
      char [] a = new char[50];
      fr.read(a); 
      fr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Java is that?

Comment: "alex/Desktop/1.txt" is just text. Open the other files in the same way as `File file = new File("all.txt");`

Comment: @HenryS. When I open that file how can I write that file into all.txt
I already have all text files I just want to combine them.

Comment: newOutputStream & newInputStream - [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Comment: @The documentation Can you give me an example because I am new to this

Comment: @AlexD. No problem. I'll write up a better answer.

Comment: @The documentation Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 8, it's very simple, although the following makes uses of [one of my packages](https://github.com/fge/throwing-lambdas) to account for possible I/O errors:

```
final Path dstFile = Paths.get("your/destination/file");

final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(dstFile);

final ThrowingConsumer<Path> copy = path -> Files.copy(path, out);

try (
    final OutputStream outref = out;
) {
    Stream.of("file1", "file2").map(Paths::get).forEach(copy);
}
```